Resume Builder App Fails When Processing Large Excel Dataset (1000-3000 Entries)
NOTE: I am a newbie to Power apps and Power Automate.
I'm developing a resume builder app that takes user data, populates a Word template, converts it to PDF, and then sends both the Word and PDF files via email to the user and their manager. The manager's email is fetched from an Excel backend based on the user's email ID.
This process works smoothly when there are 50-100 entries in the Excel file, but when the number of entries increases to 1000-3000, the flow fails. I need help understanding why this happens and how I can optimize or fix this issue to handle larger datasets.
I am not allowed to use any premium features.
The error log displays this when I run the flow in Power automate (when there are 1000-2000 entries):
Action 'Compose_user' failed: Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Compose_user' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language expression 'first(body('Filter_array'))['Official_Email_Id'] ' cannot be evaluated because property 'Official_Email_Id' cannot be selected. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.


I tried with lesser number of entries around 100 and it was working perfectly fine, the emails were getting sent to the corresponding user and manager wrt Employee_ID.
I also tried the Pagination (dividing the excel sheet into multiple chunks) but i was unsuccessful.
